# Basic Compositor for Dummies (Solved)

Tags: compositing-nodes, properties

**Solved- I realized that I was working on is compositor is for "world shader" while what I am needing is Shade Editor. Thank you either way! Like I said, "for Dummies" because I am one! haha**

I don't really feel the flow of compositor yet. Still learning, can someone simple explain in a sentence or two because what I am asking is so simple.

[image: I am learning on make glow in render in compositor]

[image: This did show up before but I cant figure how to get this node show up so I can edit emission to change color and etc..]

I am trying to understand as I try to make material glow by use compositor and then check texture on material but it doesn't show up in compositor... Is the compositor will only show one 'viewport" not shift to new one when I work on different material or object in same scene? Such as properties not changes in compositor when I want to work on other object/material.

(Clarify) How can I get this Principled BSDF node show up? While I am currently have those nodes for render to edit glow.

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots? It would help to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: The compositor works with the render layers data generated on a full render (F12).  It won't be updated with new material data unless you render again.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: There's a compositing tutorial for beginners [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEpVyEi1Hts) which might help.

Comment: @JohnEason I meant to ask as how can I get Principled BSDF node show up on compositor? I have been struggle to get this show up.

Comment: The Principled BSDF node isn't available in the compositor. If you follow that tutorial, you render your scene first and then use the rendered image as the input to the compositor which you then modify with denoise, RGB Curves, etc, etc, to create your final output. ...And having now seen the edit at the top of your question, I see that you've now realised that you should have been using the Shader Editor!